# How to handle async/await promises for lookup fields in Dynamics 365 WebResources

Tags: javascript, async-await, dynamics-crm, webapi

I am trying to make an async call for the function I am using to fetch lookup records from another entity. However, when I debug the code every value was fetched correctly, but still it showing all the records instead of the filtered ones.

```
async function addMasterContratLookupFilter(formContext) {
    'use strict';
    debugger;
    var mzk_subcontract = formContext.getAttribute("mzk_subcontract").getValue();
    if (mzk_subcontract !== null) {
        var mzk_subcontractId = null;

        if (mzk_subcontract !== null && mzk_subcontract.length > 0) {
            mzk_subcontractId = mzk_subcontract[0].id;
            mzk_subcontractId = mzk_subcontractId.replace(/[{}]/g, "");
        }

        var query = '<fetch>'
            + '<entity name="mzk_contractmanagement">'
            + '<attribute name="mzk_contractmanagementid" />'
            + '<attribute name="mzk_mastercontractagreement" />'
            + '<order attribute="mzk_subcontract" descending="false" />'
            + '<filter type="and">'
            + '<condition attribute="mzk_contractmanagementid" operator="eq" value="' + mzk_subcontractId + '" />'
            + '<condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />'
            + '<condition attribute="mzk_contracttypevalue" operator="eq" value="275380001" />'
            + '</filter>'
            + '</entity>'
            + '</fetch>';

        query = "?fetchXml=" + encodeURIComponent(query);
        try {
         const results = await Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("mzk_contractmanagement", query);
            if (results.entities.length > 0) {
                var values = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < results.entities.length; i++) {
       values += "<value>" + results.entities[i]["_mzk_mastercontractagreement_value"] + "</value>";
                }

                if (values !== '') {

                    var fetchXml = '<filter type="and">'
                        + '<condition attribute="mzk_contractmanagementid" operator="in">'
                        + values
                        + '</condition>'
                        + '</filter>';
                                        formContext.getControl("mzk_mastercontractagreement").addCustomFilter(fetchXml);
              
}
                else {
..........
                }

            }
            else {
..........
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }
```

and this is the function called on onLoad, calling the above function:

```
async function PopulateMasterContractAgreement(executionContext) {
    'use strict';

    const formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

    if (formContext.getAttribute("mzk_subcontract") !== null && formContext.getAttribute("mzk_subcontract").getValue() !== null) {
        formContext.getControl("mzk_mastercontractagreement").addPreSearch(async function () {
            await addMasterContratLookupFilter(formContext);
        });
    }

}
```

When I debugged the code, after the above function is executed, it comes to this point **await addMasterContratLookupFilter(formContext);** when I hover it, it is showing:
[[Prototype]]
:
Promise
[[PromiseState]]
:
"pending"
[[PromiseResult]]
:
undefined

I actually converted from XrmServiceToolkit. Now I am using XrmWebApi to handle queries. I want correct records to be shown in my lookup field